# Angular Js ng-repeat iterating over JSON

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am new to stackoverflow, please correct my mistakes.

Following is my JSON:

```
newTodo = {
            title: "task 1",
            cat: "category 1",
        };
```

Similarly

```
newTodo = {
            title: "task 2",
            cat: "category 1",
        }; 


        newTodo = {
            title: "task 3",
            cat: "category 3",
        };
```

Now in my HTML, how should I write code like:

```
<li ng-repeat="todo in todos">

            {{todo.title}}
            {{todo.cat}}

</li>
```

But above is wrong, I want tasks to be shown category wise like:

category 1: task list
category 2: task list

Please help. Please tell me if question is not clear.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Sajan!

Comment: maybe this if you want to order it by category ng-repeat="todo in todos order by todo.cat"
Question is not really clear.

Comment: you need to make and array of objects

Comment: like this [{"title":"task"},{"title":"task"}]

Comment: @Sajan Nagpal : check my answer, and let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.todos = [{
    "title": "Task1",
    "cat": "Cat1"
  }, {
    "title": "Task2",
    "cat": "Cat1"
  }, {
    "title": "Task1",
    "cat": "Cat2"
  }];

  var reduced = {};

  $scope.todos.map(function(item) {
    reduced[item.cat] = reduced[item.cat] || [];
    reduced[item.cat].push(item.title);
  });

  $scope.reducedOutput = reduced;
});
```

```css
li{
 color: red; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
 
  <ul ng-repeat="(key, value) in reducedOutput">
    {{key}}
    <li ng-repeat="title in value">{{title}}</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Good answer. Vote up.

Comment: @SajanNagpal Stackoverflow is quick but you should not consider it as a code generator. The answer is a copy/paste of one of my previous answer... You should search yourself first

Comment: @Weedoze .. Okay ... Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can write it like this:

```
$scope.newToDo = {
            title: "task 2",
            cat: "category 1",
        };
```

And than in html

```
<li ng-repeat="todo in newToDo ">    
   {{todo.title}}
   {{todo.cat}}    
</li>
```

Or in Table:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="todo in newToDo">
    <td>{{todo.title}}:<span style="font-weight: bold"> {{todo.cat}}</span></td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: but it shows all the tasks along with categories like (task1, category1),(task2, category1), (task3, category3) ..... I want it like this: (category 1: task 1, task2) , (category 3: task3, task 4)

Comment: Than as Jigar7521 said you must construct your json data to come like he described.

Comment: @error505 he **must** not change his json. He can still use his json structure

Answer (score 0):

You can make json like :

```
var allTask = [
                {
                cat: 'category 1'
                task : { title: "task 1", title: "task 2", title: "task 3"}
                },
                {
                cat: 'category 2'
                task : { title: "task 1", title: "task 2", title: "task 3"}
                }
        ]
```

Comment: but creating JSON is not under my control, it is coming to me created like that.

Comment: So you can push your json everytime when it comes to you like allTask .push({ title: "task 1", title: "task 2", title: "task 3"});

Answer (score 0):

create a component called  todoList

```
angular.
    module('TodoApp').
    component('todoList', {
      template:
        '<ul>' +
          '<li ng-repeat="newTodo in $ctrl.newTodos ">' +
             '<span>{{newTodo .title}}</span>' +
              '<p>{{newTodo .cat}}</p>' +
          '</li>' +
        '</ul>',
    controller: function TodoListController() {
      this.newTodos = [
      {
        title: "task 2",
        cat: "category 1"
      }, {
         title: "task 2",
        cat: "category 1"
      }
    ];
  }
});
```

Then create view file like this

```
<body ng-app="TodoApp">      
   < todo-list></todo-list>
</body>
```

Comment: Why the directive ?

Comment: To organize our code by feature area, instead of by function.

Comment: so is there any wrong using directive in those ? there are no standard that where to use directive and not. But using directive will simplify the code.Its a good habit to practice using of  directive